# Boot error - [22,874755] Ext4-fs (sda2): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-name=Ubuntu" or missing value

Tags: 12.10, boot, partitioning

I receive the above error message, followed by:

```
Root filesystem check failed. A maintenance shell will now be started. 
Root@xxxx:~#
```

How do I fix this? I have Ubuntu 12.10.

I had previously made changes in the "Disk" application, under "Edit File System Label".  What I wanted to do is label my 3 partitions: Windows, Ubuntu, and Swap.  How can I do this without causing a boot error?
I am using the Ubuntu Live CD to get to the internet.
Thanks,
A4Skyhawk

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a bug in the disk utility.  It seems to have added an invalid option to your /etc/fstab.  Edit the file and remove the goofy "x-gvfs-name=Ubuntu" part:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
nano /etc/fstab
```

Edit, and save

```
reboot
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that (at both the sign in prompt and the maintenance shell prompt), but it would not allow me to save the changes because the file is read only.  The line for the Ubuntu partition in fstab reads "/ ext4 errors=remount-ro,x-gvs-name=Ubuntu 0 1".  Can you tell me what the new/installed wording is?  TIA,  A4Skyhawk

Comment: @A4Skyhawk, did you skip the first `mount` command?  And just delete the ",x-gvfs-name=Ubuntu" part.

Comment: I had no success w/ "/ ext4 errors=remount-ro, 0 1", "/ ext4 errors=remount, 0 1", or repeating the aforesaid but removing the comma before the 0.  A4Skyhawk

Comment: I just tried the mount and nano command lines again, and get "permission denied".

Answer (score 1):

@psusi, as you noted, the failed boot was due to the invalid option ("x-gvfs-name=Ubuntu") which was in the /etc/fstab file, and which I had caused to be entered as I described in the OP.  I was able to use the Ubuntu Live CD to get to this file and edit out the problem option by the following steps:  sudo fdisk -l THEN  sudo mkdir /mnt/harddrive THEN  sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/**sde2** /mnt/harddrive THEN  sudo gedit /mnt/harddrive/etc/fstab. **Sde2** is the location of the Ubuntu root found in fdisk.  In gedit, edit out the unwanted option, save, and reboot w/o Ubuntu Live CD.  I found this procedure at http://ubuntugeek.com/forum/index.php?topic=202.0.